# iPad AirPlay and Mirroring SDK Support

Tags: ios, ipad, airplay

Not sure if I have seen it the docs, but I don't see anything relating to enabling AirPlay Mirroring from within an iOS app. Has anyone done this before? or is this something done only outside of the App.

Also with AirPlay, since it only supports Audio/Video, would we have to convert to PDF documents into Images for AirPlay?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question (you should really create two issues for this), I've answered over here:

[Airplay from iPad - a separate UIView to display on Apple TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587218/airplay-from-ipad-a-separate-uiview-to-display-on-apple-tv/8904201#8904201)

Regarding your second question, if the user has enabled Airplay mirroring, the Apple TV screen is available to draw to as a UIScreen in exactly the same way as the iOS device primary display, so you would present PDF content in whatever way you are on the iPhone or iPad (via a UIView).