# iOS AirPlay (not mirroring)

Tags: ios, airplay

I am new  to using AirPlay. I wanted to find out how we can create a specific UI layout for when AirPlay is used.

I am developing an app for iOS. When the user uses iOS mirroring, I want to take advantage of the screen real estate and display all my pages into 1 nicely designed screen.

I dont know what this is called or where to begin looking.

Real Racing 3 does this by displaying the game on the TV and a map of the track on the iOS device.

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` has a property `airPlayVideoActive`. Maybe that will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display one thing on iPad and another on Apple Tv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603611/display-one-thing-on-ipad-and-another-on-apple-tv)

Comment: rmaddy. Post it as an answer so I can give you credit