# How can I create a multi-screen experience for an iPad Pro using Unity3D?

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, ipad

For years, Apple has offered the ability to display different content on a connected screen than the content on the iOS device that's driving it.

Is there a way to use this functionality with an app built in Unity? i.e., the iPad would display one camera view, and a TV connected over HDMI via the USB-C connector would display a different camera view?

The Apple documentation article is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/windows_and_screens/displaying_content_on_a_connected_screen), and a nice walkthrough is [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/adding-external-display-support-to-your-ios-app-is-ridiculously-easy/).

[This article](https://medium.com/@SoCohesive/unity-how-to-build-a-bridge-ios-to-unity-with-swift-f23653f6261) explains how to send messages between Unity and Swift, but it seems rather limited in scope.

Comment: Support for a second screen has existed for many years. See [Display one thing on iPad and another on Apple Tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603611/display-one-thing-on-ipad-and-another-on-apple-tv) (the answer uses Objective-C code but it's the same APIs in Swift). There's nothing special about supporting it on the iPad Pro.

Comment: Maybe like this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiDisplay.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the normal Unity MultiDisplay workflow isn't supported by iOS, so the solution is a little trickier:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MultiScreen : MonoBehaviour
{

    // set the two cameras via the inspector
    public Camera primaryCam;
    public Camera secondaryCam;

    void Start()
    {
        // render the primary camera to the main display
        primaryCam.SetTargetBuffers(Display.main.colorBuffer, Display.main.depthBuffer);

        secondaryCam.depth = primaryCam.depth - 1;
        secondaryCam.enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // only render the second display if it is attached
        if (Display.displays.Length > 1 && !secondaryCam.enabled)
        {
            // set the second display's resolution
            Display.displays[1].SetRenderingResolution(Display.displays[1].systemWidth, Display.displays[1].systemHeight);

            // render the secondary camera to the second display
            secondaryCam.SetTargetBuffers(Display.displays[1].colorBuffer, Display.displays[1].depthBuffer);
        }

        // activate the second camera and render pipeline if a second display is connected
        secondaryCam.enabled = Display.displays.Length > 1;
    }

}
```

Additionally, I had to make sure `Auto Graphics API` was deactivated in `Project Settings > Player > Other Settings > Rendering`, and that `Metal` was removed from the following list. Setting the `Company Name`, `Product Name`, and `Bundle Identifier` may have also helped.