# using swift can we airplay photos on Apple TV programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv, airplay

I want to build a simple app in iOS using swift which shows the photos of the album in my app and on button click it should airplay on my Apple TV.

I read so many documents and articles but not sure if we can do it for photos. Few have said for audio/video it is possible but not sure about photos.

At least any links or sample code would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231868/ipad-airplay-and-mirroring-sdk-support not sure whether will work or not

Comment: There is no API to do it without user interaction . You may be able to use AVRoutePickerView to let the user select a destination from within your app if you are using the AV framework to show the photos.

Comment: @Paulw11, please help! Can I mirror the app screen rather than showing photos/videos in swift programmatically? Any idea to mirroring ios app on airplay supported/smart tv programmatically?

Comment: @Paulw11, please put a comment here if possible, I did not get the exact starting clue still. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188566061?pli=1

Comment: I do not believe that there is any api to mirror the device screen programmatically. The user needs to do it via control center. A lightning to hdmi adapter mirrors the screen automatically.

Answer (score 4):

A user should connect the to Apple TV at Control Center via AirPlay:

[image: Control center]
[image: AirPlay]

Then you can use Apple TV as second screen of the app.

1. Check if the app have external display:

   ```
   if UIScreen.screens.count > 1 {
       // External display is connected ...
   }
   ```
2. Create new UIScreen for external window:

   ```
   if let externalScreen = UIScreen.screens.last {
       externalWindow = UIWindow()
       externalWindow.screen = externalScreen
       configureExternalWindow(externalWindow)
       externalWindow.isHidden = false
   }
   ```
3. And use it as you want to display photo albums:

   ```
   // In our Collection View selection callback
   if inSingleDisplayMode {
       photoViewController.photo = photo
       navigationController?.pushViewController(photoViewController, animated: true)
   } else {
       showOnExternalDisplay(photo)
   }
   ```

Additional information at WWDC sessions:

[Adding Delight to your iOS App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/233/)

[AirPlay and External Displays in iOS apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/406/)

Comment: thanks for example, let me try and I will update on same.

Comment: @Anton, Can I mirroring the app screen rather showing photo/video in swift programmatically in swift? Any idea to mirroring ios app on airplay supported/smart tv ?